# How to call a mailer action in a controller from a link_to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call a mailer I have in the `create` action in my `interests` controller:

```
  def create
       if @interest.save
            UserMailer.interest_to_seller(@interest).deliver_now
  etc....
```

This works great when I'm going to the CRUD /interest/new form and creating it there, but I'm actually trying to call this from a post method in a different place. It's as if the `create` actions is being skipped all together, but that's impossible because the record is being created, right?

My routes.rb:

```
 resources :seller_listings do
     post :add_interest, on: :member
  end
```

And in my view:

```
 <%= link_to add_interest_seller_listings_path(m), method: :post do %>
    Add Interest & Fire Email!
 <%end%>
```

And in the interest controller, I have this action that that the post in the routes file calls:

```
 def add_interest
     current_user.mark_buyer_interest(seller_listing)
```

Which references this in the user.rb:

```
 def mark_buyer_interest(listing)
     buyer_interests.create(seller_listing: listing.id, accepted_by_seller: 0)
 end
```

This works well, records are created, but the Mailer is skipped. Any suggestions? I've never done it this way before so any advice would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call `UserMailer.interest_to_seller(@interest).deliver_now` again in `mark_buyer_interest`.

```
def mark_buyer_interest(listing)
  new_interest = buyer_interests.create(seller_listing: listing.id, accepted_by_seller: 0)
  UserMailer.interest_to_seller(new_interest).deliver_now
end
```

Comment: Yes, you have to call Mailer every time, when you want to send email. You need to think, maybe in some other cases you will use `mark_buyer_interest` method without sending email, just move UserMailer call to the controller action in this case

Comment: Thanks the the help!